# FutureTask currency design

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

in `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask#run`

```
public void run() {
    if (state != NEW ||
        !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                     null, Thread.currentThread()))
        return;
    try {
        Callable<V> c = callable;
        if (c != null && state == NEW) {
            V result;
            boolean ran;
            try {
                result = c.call();
                ran = true;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                ran = false;
                setException(ex);
            }
            if (ran)
                set(result);
        }
    } finally {
        // runner must be non-null until state is settled to
        // prevent concurrent calls to run()
        runner = null;
        // state must be re-read after nulling runner to prevent
        // leaked interrupts
        int s = state;
        if (s >= INTERRUPTING)
            handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(s);
    } }
```

what's mean of finally block comment ?

1. run() method cannot be concurrent called, because of the CAS .
2. why must wait the INTERRUPTING -> INTERRUPTED state transform finished ?

thank you !

Comment: I add the class, you can read source code of idk 1.8

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't notice that this was the JDK's FutureTask.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wonder if that's a typo in in the comment, and that they really mean "to prevent concurrent calls to cancel()"